# Attempting to click on a child hyperlink with puppeteer js

Tags: puppeteer

I have the following html:

```
<td id="content_PDB_Dashboard_UC_SharedLeads_gvSharedLeads_tccell0_6" class="dxgv dx-ellipsis" align="left" style="border-bottom-width:0px;" title="
                                1905 Saint Louis Avenue 
                            " dxellipsistitle="true">
                                <a onclick="return ShowCallDialog(472919, 7);">1905 Saint Louis Avenue </a>
                            </td>
```

There are multiple of these on a page.  I need to loop through and click on each link.  The 'a'.
Here is my attempt:

```
  const allProperties = await page.$$('.dxgv, .dx-ellipsis > a');
    allProperties.map(el => {
     el.click();
    })
```

The error I receive is:

```
Error: Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `map` doesn't execute asynchronously, replace it with a simple `for loop` or `Promise.all`.
2. if there is no constraint on using `HTMLElement.click`, use that instead ([issue](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/2977)).

```js
const anchors = await page.$$('.dxgv, .dx-ellipsis > a');
for (let anchor of anchors)
    await page.evaluate(el => el.click(), anchor);
```

Comment: Excellent!  Any idea why it clicks on the last anchor only? @mbit

Comment: Or maybe it starts clicking from the last one added?  @mbit

Comment: @FabricioG do you have a page or example to share?

Comment: Yes how do I send to you?  It requires username and password @mbit